# Why is the file `vite.svg` in the `dist` folder when building with Vite library mode?

Tags: javascript, vite

I am trying to publish a React component as an npm module using the [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) of Vite. But even though my entry file does not import or use the image `vite.svg` it is copied to the dist folder.

vite.config.js:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx'),
      name: 'MyLib',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'my-lib',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

src/index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

export function Button(props) {
  return <button {...props} />;
}
```

dist

```
dist
 ┣ my-lib.js
 ┣ my-lib.umd.cjs
 ┗ vite.svg
```

Comment: Where is the file copied from?

Comment: I did find the issue and are writing an answer atm.

Answer (score 6):

By default, Vite will automatically copy all files inside `publicDir` into the `outDir` when building. The default value of `publicDir` is `public` and this folder (with the file `vite.svg`) is created when starting a new project with `npm create vite`.

The easiest way to get rid of this file is to just delete the `public` folder.

There is also [an option](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-copypublicdir) `copyPublicDir` that can be set to `false` in order to disable this behavior and not copy any files from the set `publicDir` to `outDir`.

Comment: Right - you might want to consider using a more minimal template; e.g. I use my own https://github.com/akx/vite-react-ts-template for React + TypeScript apps.

Comment: @AKX how do you make vite use your template during creating? awesome if we can create our own.

Comment: @Elias My template is meant to be used with [`degit`](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit): `npx degit akx/vite-react-ts-template my-new-project`